# Shrink-To-Fit while floating bottom

Tags: html, css, css-float

See the box stuck the bottom right. Right now it as a fixed height of 300px. Instead I would like to be just as high as necessary. Meaning I need the height to adjust automatically to the content. When I remove the height property it assumes full height.

Additionally, I would like to be able to "refresh" the height whenever I update the content via javascript (jQuery).

Comment: That looks *much better* than your first design (I remember your older questions).

Comment: thanks ;) they agreed to put it at the bottom instead of sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your seeing a height of 100% because your style for `html, body, div, iframe` specifies height of 100%. To override this, just set your height to "auto". Like this:

```
div.sidebar {
  border-left: thin solid #66CCFF;
  border-right: thin solid #66CCFF;
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto; /* <-- New Value */
  /*height: 300px; <-- Old Value */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  width: 200px;
```

}

This will size the box so that it is only the same size as the content. You might also want to consider using the `max-height` property to set an upper limit though. Say something like `max-height:640px;`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this properties:

```
div.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: auto;
}
```

I think you won't need jquery to change height, just change content.

Comment: Cheers :) As long as it gets the work done. Although if you plan to always have this element floating regardless to the rest of the page I would use fixed position. It just feels right :D

Comment: actually you are right, I used yours, I didn't notice they were different.

Answer (score 1):

Change `height: 300px;` to `height: auto;`.